# smooch bot does not return auto reply

Tags: bots, reply, smooch

For some reason the auto response returned by the bot does not work. I type "Hey" but get no 'answer' from the bot.

I have read all topics.
My heroku is properly pointing to the url.
The email notifications are coming through.
The whispers are working properly
I replaced the script.js file with the original one (used by EstherBot)

Yet nothing happens...

anybody a clue?

thanks

Wouter

Comment: https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example#troubleshooting-your-bot

Comment: i have got heroku belt in place but it just doesnt say error or anything - nothing that tells me I did something wrong

Comment: Does it say anything at all? There's not much here to work with.

Comment: does this help?

State changed from starting to up
2016-07-10T15:33:54.723978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=independi.herokuapp.com request_id=88537c60-0601-478c-9343-14c341d06155 fwd="213.46.87.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=72ms status=200 bytes=1181
2016-07-10T15:33:55.639301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=independi.herokuapp.com request_id=24887414-a7c7-4fbb-bd9c-3ad33a738b99 fwd="213.46.87.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=222

Comment: I see nothing wrong there. You might consider starting fresh with Estherbot or smooch-bot-example and work forward from there. A link to your GitHub repo might also be helpful

Comment: I'm afraid I just have to start over again... sigh

Answer (score 0):

Right - fixed it.
I went back to earlier versions - but in vain.
I then killed all whispers - but no result.
I then replace all code manually with the original code - but no result.

Basically I just went back to the drawing board and reinstalled it (as was suggested already by @AndrewLavers).

It only means I actually have not been able to figure out the why.... which is a pitty.

CLOSED